# Replacing an image with the media only tag?

Tags: css

When i reduce the page width to 1500 the code works and the about is taken away. However the code is ignoring the original about small display none. When i load the page the about small image is displayed.

https://gyazo.com/813b8470136d3b68c4bece744a5dec9e

```
.aboutsmall{
   display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px){
   .about{
    display: none;
   }

   .aboutsmall{
    display: all;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mispelled something...

```
.aboutsmall{
   display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px){
   .about{
    display: none;
   }

   .aboutsmall{
    display: block;
   }
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem with ignoring the about small display none when the page first loads.

Comment: Fixed it, just used opacity tags instead and worked fine.